# Drupal Form APi Checkbox states

Tags: ajax, forms, api, drupal, checkbox

So I have create my checkbox in my form

```
$form['existing_customer'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Are you an existing customer'),
    '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'checkbox_selected',
    'wrapper' => 'subject',
),);
```

This calls my function and changes the values in my checkbox

The problem is I cannot get it to switch back if it is unchecked

```
function checkbox_selected(&$form, &$form_state) {
    if ($form_state['values']['existing_customer'] == 1) {

        $my_options = array( 'select' => t('Select'), 'mr' => t('Mr'), 'mrs' => t('Mrs'), 'miss' => t('Miss'), 'ms' =>t('Ms'), 'sir' =>t('Sir'), 'dr' => t('Dr'), 'prof' => t('Prof') );

    }
    elseif ($form_state['values']['existing_customer'] == 0){
        $my_options = array( 'seconfZ' => t('jimmy'), 'mr' => t('Mr'), );

    }
    $form['subject'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Subject'),
        '#options' => $my_options//$form['subject_options']['#value']
    );
    return $form['subject'];
}
```

I thought I could do a switch on the checkbox value or state but no joy?

Comment: Does your callback actually get called? I don't see "callback" as an attribute in the form API, but I do see a "#value_callback"

Comment: it gets called, what do you mean "#value_callback"?

Comment: What version are you using? I generally use this as a reference, and that was where I didn't see it so I wasn't sure if your method was getting called, and also what it should return if it did. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#value_callback

Answer (score 2):

Oftentimes, when you use the Form API `#ajax` system, the `wrapper` that you specify is actually replaced with another element AFTER `drupal_html_id()` has been called again on the element wrapper. So I would check the markup of the "subject" element in Firebug/Web Inspector after your AJAX stuff happens--I'm betting that the wrapper div is now something like "subject--1".

To fix this, you need to manually set a wrapper div on the item you are replacing--one that won't change when the form is rebuilt. For example, in your form builder:

```
$form['existing_customer'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => t('Are you an existing customer'),
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'checkbox_selected',
    'wrapper' => 'subject-wrapper',
  ),
);
$form['subject'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div id="subject-wrapper">',
  ...
  `#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I remember that problem. I think I got around it using a really hacky fix but this seems a very likely solution. Will bookmark this for reference, am doing some forms quite soon.